# How to find integer solutions to $(pk-1)(p-1)(p+1)=(p-2)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a **prime**. How can we find whether there is a positive integer $k$ satisfying the equation,
$$(pk-1)(p-1)(p+1)=(p-2)!$$

Clearly there are no solutions when $p=2,3$. What about for other primes $p$ ?

(I want to find prime numbers $p$ such that $(p^2-p)(p^2-1)|p!$. Since $(p-2)!=1\mod p$, we get that there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $(pk-1)(p^2-1)=(p-2)!$ iff $(p^2-p)(p^2-1)|p!$. )

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: just solve the equation: $k=(1+\frac{(p-2)!}{(p-1)(p+1)})/p$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But then how do you know $k$ is an integer?

Comment: Are there any conditions on $p$? Because if p=3 then we get $(3k-1)(2)(4)=1!$

Comment: @IrbidMath That only mean that for $p=3$ there's no solution. The OP didn't claim that always were one.

Comment: I want to find all primes where there is a solution for $k$.

Comment: It better to focus on the divisibility $p^2-1 \mid (p-2)!$ than trying to find a solution to the equation.

Comment: @jjagmath then the question should said find $p$ prime and $k$ integer such that...

Comment: @IrbidMath No, it shouldn't. Because then $p=11, k=275$ would solve the problem. But the OP wants to know for which primes there is such $k$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Study the small cases first. Then use that $$\left(\frac{p-1}{2}, \frac{p+1}{2}\right)=1$$